# HAML: How to add conditional classes to tags the right way?

Tags: class, haml

We often do the following in HAML:

```
%li{ class: "#{'active' if action_name == 'index'}" }
```

This looks really ugly, and intuitively I'd like to do it the following way:

```
%li{ class: 'active' if action_name == 'index' }
```

But this results in `syntax error, unexpected modifier_if, expecting ')'`.

Is there a nicer way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need parentheses:

```
%li{class: ('active' if true)}
```

If you wanted, you could create a helper [attribute method](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#attribute_methods):

```
def active_if_index(action_name)
  if action_name == 'index'
    {class: 'active'}
  else
    {}
  end
end
```

Then you could use t like this:

```
%li{active_if_index(action_name)}
```

Comment: Thank you. Needless to say that [SLIM](https://github.com/slim-template/slim) does this (among many other things) a lot more beautiful: `li class=active_if_index(action_name)`.